# Is there interest in this elementary equivalent of the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

It can be shown that the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the following:

Let $B$ be the Meissel-Mertens constant, $p$ prime, and $\theta(x)=\sum_{p\le x}\log p$.  Then, $\sum_{p\le x}1/p-\log\log x-B>0$ when $\theta(x)\ge x$.

Is this of any (practical) interest?  Should I ask this question in MO? The resemblance of the LHS of the inequality to a similar expression in Mertens’ second theorem is not coincidental; something similar holds for the other two theorems of Mertens.